# Rails - bind a function with Model instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have fully designed database which is working very fine,showing data from the database and all stuff.
There is an option in cameras DB "is_online"

am getting it as `<%= camera.is_online %>` . 
what i want to do is to bind a function with this, which will color it, on basic of Yes and No, if its Yes it will be green and if its No it will be red.
Problem. Where to define such method which will available to this on Camera/_camera view
so i can do something like `<%= camera.is_online.color %>`
PS: i have seen a word decorator same as am binding .color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to create an instance method:

```
#app/models/camera.rb
class Camera < ActiveRecord::Base
   def color
      is_online? ? "green" : "red"
   end
end
```

This would allow you to call:

```
@camera.color
```

---

You could use a [translator](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models), which I've since found would have to be used in connection with a [custom method](http://blog.peschla.net/2015/02/translating-attribute-values-in-rails/) (otherwise it gets very messy):

```
#Gemfile
gem "human_attribute_values"

#View
<%= camera.human_attribute_values(:is_online) %>

#config/locales/en.yml
en:
  activerecord:
    values:
      camera:
        is_online:
          'true':  "green"
          'false': "red"
```

This is a bit more long-winded than I imagined, but it's a way to achieve what you need.

---

The other option, as you've mentioned, is to use [*decorators*](https://github.com/drapergem/draper), which basically allow you to create custom attributes that are dependent on the values in your current attributes:

```
#Gemfile
gem 'draper', '~> 1.3'

#app/decorators/camera_decorator.rb
class CameraDecorator < Draper::Decorator
  def color
    object.is_online? ? "green" : "red"
  end
end

#app/controllers/cameras_controller.rb
class CamerasController < ApplicationController
   def show
       @camera = Camera.find(params[:id]).decorate
   end
end
```

Being honest, it's probably more hassle than it's worth to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Rails view helpers look to be your answer here.

## in app/helpers/application_helper.rb

```
def colourize text
    colour = (text == "yes" ? "green" : "dark gray")
    content_tag span, text, style: "color: #{colour}"
end
```

Then in your view use

```
<%= colourize camera.is_online %>
```